# Condition of equality, power set of union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to know on what condition we have : $P(A) \cup P(B) = P(A \cup B)$ ?

Where is the mistake ?

$P(A \cup B) \subset P(A)\cup P(B) \iff \forall z, z \subset (A\cup B) \Longleftarrow ((z \subset A)\cup(z \subset B)) $

And I have an other question : what about $P(A Δ B)$, $P(A $ \ $ B)$ ?

Thanks !

Comment: You mean :
$$P(A) \cup P(B) = P(A \cup B)$$

Comment: @Essaidi yes it's a mistake !

Comment: Notice that $A \cup B \in P(A \cup B)$ then $A \cup B \in P(A)$ or $A \cup B \in P(B)$ $\cdots$.

Comment: That third line is an absolute mess, and the lack of parentheses make it worse. It should be $\forall z\Bigl( \bigl( (z\subset A)\vee (z\subset B)\bigr)\to \bigl(z\subset A\cup B\bigr)\Bigr)$; that is equivalent to $P(A)\cup P(B)\subset P(A\cup B)$, not to the reversed inclusion that you state.

Answer (score 1):

If :
$$P(A) \setminus P(B) \subset P(A \setminus B)$$
then :
$$\left(P(A) \setminus P(B)\right) \cup P(B) \subset P(A \setminus B) \cup P(B)$$
then :
$$P(A) \subset P(A \setminus B) \cup P(B)$$
and because $A = (A \setminus B) \cup B$ we deduce that :
$$P \left((A \setminus B) \cup B\right) \subset P(A \setminus B) \cup P(B)$$
Let $X = A \setminus B$ then :
$$P \left(X \cup B\right) \subset P(X) \cup P(B)$$
And the case of the union we deduce that :
$$A \setminus B \subset B \text{ or } B \subset A \setminus B$$
wich means that $A \subset B$ or $B = \emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the line where you've asked, "where is the mistake?": The union symbol between $(z\subset A)$ and $(z\subset B)$ should be a logical "or" symbol, it seems. Also, that implication arrow on the right should be pointing the other way: If $z$ is in the subset, then $z$ is in the superset.

As far as thinking about the union of power sets versus the power set of the union, I think it's useful to consider this: If there are elements $a\in A\setminus B$ and $b\in B\setminus A$, then $\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$ contains the set $\{a,b\}$, which is not in the union of the power sets. Thus, if you want equality, you can't have such a pair of elements.

Comment: Yes, X and Y are supposed to be A and B...

Comment: But, this equivalence is every time true ?

Comment: @ztg02, I have edited my answer now to address this.

Comment: Yess, it should be an "or" and it should be a reverse arrow , with these modifications, the equivalence is always true, but what's the condition for equality ?

Comment: Like I said in this answer, it cannot be true that both sets contain elements missing from the other. That means that at least one of them only contains elements that are present in the other, which makes it a subset.

This argument shows that IF you have equality, THEN ($A\subset B$ or $B\subset A$). To show that this is actually an equivalence, assume (wlog) that $A\subset B$, and show that the power set equation holds.

Answer (score 0):

If :
$$P(A \cup B) \subset P(A) \cup P(B)$$
then :
$$A \cup B \in P(A) \cup P(B)$$
wich means :
$$A \cup B \in P(A) \text{ or } A \cup B \in P(B)$$
so
$$A \cup B \subset A \text{ or } A \cup B \subset B$$
and we conclude that $B \subset A$ or $A \subset B$.

Comment: Thanks !! I got it ! What about if we do that with symetric difference or set difference (\) ? @Essaidi

Comment: We have : $$P(A \setminus B) \subset P(A) \setminus P(B)$$